# Allow self-signed PHP on localhost? (Disable SSL?)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

```
<?php
$content = [ 'http' => [ 'method' => 'GET' ], 'ssl' => [ 'verify_peer' => false, 'allow_self_signed'=> true ] ];
$url = 'http://localhost/server-status';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( 'Current' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</dl>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
?>
```

I am trying to disable SSL so my PHP can get some stats from server-status for the admin panel, but localhost always goes to https which means PHP cannot get the content due to SSL being enabled and not valid on localhost.

How do I disable this when I am doing file_get_contents?

Comment: Why not have your server trust the certificate? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list

Comment: Is that first line supposed to be `$context` instead of `$content`? You're also not passing it to the `file_get_contents` call. Alternatively you could call `stream_context_set_default` with that context, which would take effect automatically.

Comment: @iainn How would I do this, could you post an answer please to help me figure out where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the stream context you've created to the `file_get_contents` call:

```
$context = stream_context_create(['ssl' => [ 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false, 'allow_self_signed'=> true ] ]);

$content = file_get_contents('https://localhost/', false, $context);
```

I've added in the `verify_peer_name` option here, but you might not need it.

Comment: GENIUS!
THANKS SO MUCH!